# Get column and row from cursor position in NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

I use the following code to get the cursor position from my `NSTextView`:

```
NSRange range = [m_textView selectedRange];
long cursorpos = range.location;
```

This works fine but how can I convert this cursor position into column and row indices? I didn't see anything about this in the documentation.

Of course, I could just export the `NSTextView`'s contents and determine column and row manually but this of course a very ugly solution... isn't there an in-house means in `NSTextView` to do such a trivial thing?

Comment: Ask the layout manager?

Comment: How exactly? I'm not familiar with the layout manager and from a quick look at the doc I don't see how it could help me to do that. Could you please point me at the specific layout manager APIs to use?